# How to fix the beginner's ReactJS error?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm beginner in ReactJS and am trying to run the following code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Hello World-React JS</h2>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var HelloWorldComponent = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function () {
            return {
                serverMessage: ''
            };
        },
        componentDidMount: function () {
            $.get('/Home/getmessage', function (result) {
                if (this.isMounted) {
                    this.setState({
                        serverMessage: result
                    });
                }
            }.bind(this));
        },
        render: function () {
            return ("<h1>{this.state.serverMessage}</h1>");
        }
    });
    ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorldComponent />, document.getElementById("helloworldcontainer"));
</script>

<div id="helloworldcontainer"></div>
```

As you can see this is VS2017 MVC simple test application.

Actually, in VS editor I have some complaints that is shown on the screen shot bellow:

[image]

How to fix it and run it?

Comment: I'd recommend you to start with `react-cli` initially if you are trying to lean React, and then move to working on how to make your own boiler plate code. Also the Syntax you are using in this code is very very out dated. I am guessing you are following some tutorial. Drop it and follow one mentioned in ReactJS documentation https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your script type as `<script type="text/babel">`

sample code :

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>demo</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"/></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        class MessageBox extends React.Component {
            constructor(props){
            super(props);
            }
            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <div className={`messageBox ${this.props.type} || hidden`}>
                            {this.props.message}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        } 

    class NameInput extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                message: {
                type: "success",
                body: "Now my message is in NameInput's state"
                }
            }
            this.buttonClicked = this.buttonClicked.bind(this);
        }

        buttonClicked(evt) {
            alert("hi");
        }

        render() {

            let msg = this.state.message;

            return (
                <div>
                <label>Name: <input type="text" /></label>
                <button onClick={this.buttonClicked}>Click me!</button>

                <MessageBox type={msg.type} message={msg.body}/>
                </div>
            )
            }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
        <NameInput />,
        document.getElementById('container')
    );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

as @Adeel Imran suggests, For just checking how react works, this is fine. For future development use babel-cli and try to write a component in a separate file.