# ReactJS 'Hello World' with JSX and classes prints nothing to browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, jsx

I'm trying to get some basic jsx to display some text in a regular web browser. By double clicking the main html file and having the code open in chrome, firefox .....

I've followed along with [a few](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) [intro tutorials](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) on those links and a few books.

[This one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vU_UZKH0UoQ) is the only one that seemed to touch on opening the program in an actual web browser. The problem is that it didn't include some of the extra stuff like creating classes and stuff that the other ones did.

I can't seem to find the reason that my code isn't printing anything

---

**Desired Output**

*Hello world*

printed in the web browser I'm using (Firefox)

---

**jsx/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class navBar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>Hello world</div>;
    }
}

render(<navBar />, document.body)
```

---

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.8.4/index.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.4/index.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.2/browser.min.js"></script>

        <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type='text/babel' src='jsx/index.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Usually you need to create a div, and give it to the render function.
Your React versions are really old, try to update to 16.8

Comment: @felixmosh I'm pretty new to react. Did I change the versions correctly?

Comment: no, 
unpkg.com/react@16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js
unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js

Comment: @Jacob Can you check this once https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/master/static/html/single-file-example.html ? and this also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48879936/4061006    and your importing like import { render } from 'react-dom'; so ReactDom.render ,here  it's ReactDOM not ReactDom, and here don't need ReactDOM, just render(<NavBar />, document.querySelector('#root')) is fine

Comment: @Jayavel Sorry, I was importing reactdom like how you mentioned, I just hadn't updated my question to show it.

The github example you posted doesn't use classes, which seems to be a big problem for me in this example. I've already been able to create a hello world without using classes. https://github.com/jacobkrahn/jsxhelloworld

The second example looks a bit more complicated. I'll read it over, but it's more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In jsx**

Remove the import statements.

Also, add brackets surrounding the div in the return statement.

Name your components with a capital letter (NavBar instead of navBar)

Use ReactDOM.render

**And for safety**

Create a Div inside the body of your html to mount your component to. This will prevent third party libraries from manipulating the body of your page.

```
class NavBar extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
                <div>
                    Hello world
                </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<NavBar />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

**In the html**
Use https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js and https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js as the source scripts

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>

            <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type='text/babel' src='jsx/index.js'></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need container with ID 'root' in index.html and you need to import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'. Also you should name components with capital letter (Navbar not navBar) that is convention. Than your code should look like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Navbar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello world</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Navbar />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

Comment: I posted an update with that, but it didn't seem to help. Would you be able to post your html as well?

Also, before I was using document.body. Is that not good enough?

Comment: You need to have <div id="root"></div> in your body in html thats the place where react renders

Comment: That still didn't seem to help. Do you have html that this is working with?
Also, I posted some updated console errors.

Answer (score 1):

According to react documentation, you are not supposed to use `class/components` names starting with a small case.

Change `navBar` to `NavBar` and you should be good to go.

Additionally, you should not mount your component to the body tag, as some third-party libraries might manipulate the body of the page.

Also, please read the console warning and errors in the developer tool, you'll get the basic answers from there.